# Xamarin Forms Xaml - Background image full cover - without stretching (hide bottom part)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xaml and having a small issue ,

basically i have a grid and i want to add a background image for it . The grid has a fixed height .

I want the image to fill the grid completely without stretching , 
css equivalent of :

```
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg");
background-size: cover;
```

If the image is too big , it will fill the whole grid but display a portion of it without stretching the image . If its too small , it will use the image as is.

Code :

```
<Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                                 Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                 Source="URL"
                                 Aspect="Fill"/>

                    </Grid>
```

i also added Aspect="Fill" for the image but it overrides the height of my grid. I want the "overflow" bottom part to be hidden and the height of the grid to be fixed .

Comment: `Aspect="AspectFill"` https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Aspect/